# STDEV.S and STDEV.P using numpy

Tags: python, numpy

If I can use the below to calculate the standard deviation of the population

```
x = ([9,2,5,4,12,7,8,11,9,3,7,4,12,5,4,10,9,6,9,4])
np.sqrt(np.sum((x - np.mean(x))**2)/len(x))
```

Is there a way to also use numpy to calculate the sample standard deviation.  I know there is a statistics.stdev which will do it but I cant seem to find a numpy version.  Is there a reason why there isnt one?

I have also tried to include `ddof` in the formula but got an error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You convert it to a numpy array and use np.std() ?

```
x = ([9,2,5,4,12,7,8,11,9,3,7,4,12,5,4,10,9,6,9,4])
np.array(x).std(ddof=1)

3.0607876523260447
```

If you do it from scratch:

```
np.sqrt(np.sum((x - np.mean(x))**2)/(len(x)-1))
3.060788
```

Or:

```
import statistics
statistics.stdev(x)
3.0607876523260447
```

Comment: You are right. Thank you.  I forgot to put the -1 in a bracket outside of the x.  My brain needs a rest.